# On 2-groups of exponent 4 and class 2

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, involutions, centralisers

Suppose A is a 2-group with the following properties:

1. $\lvert A \rvert = t^3$ with $t$ some even power of $2$;
2. $A$ and $Z(A)$ (the center of $A$) are of exponent $4$;
3. $\lvert Z(A) \rvert = t$ and $[A, A] = \sqrt{t}$;
4. $[A, A]$ is the group of involutions in $Z(A)$;
5. $A/[A, A]$ is elementary abelian.

I also have the following additional property: any two noncommuting involutions in $A$ are contained in a group isomorphic to $D_8$.

Can such groups be classified? Can one say much more about such groups (possibly under extra conditions)?

Comment: Surely the fact that $A$ has exponent $4$ implies that any two noncommuting involutions generate a group isomorphic to $D_8$? Or did you mean any two noncommuting elements of $A$ rather than involutions? I would expect there to be vast numbers of groups satisfying these conditions, and no hope of a classification.

Comment: @DerekHolt: you are right, I edited the question. I also have the following strong extra restrictions: there are $t + 1$ elementary abelian subgroups $A_0,\ldots, A_t$ of order $t$ such that for all different $i, j, k$, $A_iZ(A) \cap A_j = \{ 1 \}$ and $A_iA_j \cap A_k = \{ 1 \}$. Could this help ?

Comment: Does not this just amount to computing a certain (easily describable) subgroup in $H^2(\mathbb F_2^{5n};\mathbb F_2^n)$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: can you explain the details ? (Certainly, the extra conditions I mentioned to Derek Holt will be needed.)

Comment: I only mean that $A$ is a central extension of $A/[A,A]$ which is elementary abelian of order $2^{5n}$ by $[A,A]$ which is also elementary abelian of order $2^n$.

Comment: The smallest possible order is $64$ where a small computer computation shows that there is exactly one such group namely the central product $C_4\circ 2^{1+4}$ (the central product of a cyclic group of order $4$ and an extraspecial group of order $32$).

Comment: @THC Your extra conditions seems to be asking whether Payne's Conjecture is true. This is a very hard open problem. See the paper by Bamberg, Glasby, Swartz, AS-configurations and skew-translation generalised quadrangles,  J. Algebra 421 (2015), 311--330. This paper has some group theoretic constraints on $G$ and proves that there is no example with t=8 (using a computer search).